# hbase custom filter not working

Tags: filter, hbase

I'm trying to create a custom filter on hbase 0.98.1 in standalone mode on ubuntu 14.04.

I created a class extending FilterBase. I put the jar in HBASE_HOME/lib. Looking in the logs, I see that my jar is in the path.

Then I have a java client that first makes a get with a columnPrfixFilter, then it makes a get with my custom filter. The columnPrefixFilter works perfectly fine. With my filter, nothing happens. The client freeze for 10 minutes and close the connexion.

I don't see any thing in the log.

Could you please give me some hint on what and where to check ?

regards,

***EDIT:***
It turns out to be a protc vesrion conflict. I generated java class form proto file with protoc 2.4.0 and in my filter I was using protobuf-java 2.5.0
I aligned to 2.5.0 and it's now working fine.